# WinForms Mouse Capture

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Windows Forms application and I need to capture the mouse movements outside my window. My simplified code in my window class is:

```
private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Capture = true;
    MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
}

private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Out.Write("!");
}
```

As you see, when user presses a button, my program should start tracking mouse (even if it is outside of window - this is a key featue!) But I get really strange behavior. If I move mouse inside the window, everything is great, **!** are written to console. But when I move mouse outside of the window, only OnMouseMove is called only once (and the point is really outside). Then if I move mouse anywhere outside of the window it is not called anymore. If I return mouse back to window, everything is perfect. Move away - 1 message, move in the window - OK.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a global mouse hook for that. I recommend that you first read something about hooks, eg. on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28VS.85%29.aspx). An example implementation in C# can be found at the [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you! Just studied the solution from CodeProject and it works perfectly!