# detect mouse button holding outside the form

Tags: c#

I am trying to make software witch does something when right click is held down.
At the moment it is only working if im holding right click down in form but it stops working if i try it outside the form.

and it would be cool if it could do some loop while right is held down.

I'm using c# .NET

Any kind of help is welcome!

**here is the code**

public partial class Form1 : Form

{

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]

    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy,
                  int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseDown += MouseDownFunction;
        this.MouseUp += MouseUpFunction;
    }


    public void MouseDownFunction(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)            
    {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                //Do something
                //some loop if possible
                
            }
     }

    public void MouseUpFunction(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {           
           //Ends it
        }  
        
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884590/winforms-mouse-capture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinForms Mouse Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884590/winforms-mouse-capture)